# SQL Query from multiple tables, if first join doesn't have record, then select from second, and so on

Tags: mysql, join

I want to able to pass a user id and select all the topic names and usernames from the topics/users table
where the user id is in the classes_spring table, if not no records are returned from the classes_spring table then check the classes_fall table, if not then check the classes_winter table. How can I do this with joins? I want to limit the records 10. So if the results return 100 rows, I want to be able to page the with the limit clause.

```
tables

topics
id
name


users
id
name

classes
id
name


classes_spring
id
topicid
classid
userid

classes_fall
id
topicid
name
classid


classes_winter
id
topicid
name
classid
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? And where you got stucked?

Comment: @Tarang

I've tried this:
Select distinct t.id, t.name

FROM topics t
LEFT JOIN classes_spring cs ON cs.topicid=t.id AND cs.userid=13
LEFT JOIN classes_fall cf ON cf.topicid=t.id AND cf.userid=13 AND cf.userid<>cs.userid
LEFT JOIN classes_winter cw ON cw.topicid=t.id AND cw.userid=13 AND cf.userid<>cs.userid AND cw.userid<>cs.userid

WHERE (cs.topicid IS NOT NULL OR cf.topicid IS NOT NULL OR cw.topicid IS NOT NULL) 
LIMIT 0, 10